# Why I Can't binding value to my Custom Directive?

Tags: angular

I created a custom directive to validate my input on form:

```
import { Directive, Attribute, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

function isEmptyInputValue(value: any): boolean {
  // we don't check for string here so it also works with arrays
  return value == null || value.length === 0;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[minNumber][ngModel], [minNumber][formControll]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MinNumberValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class MinNumberValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  constructor(@Attribute('minNumber') public minNumber: number) { }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
      if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value) || isEmptyInputValue(this.minNumber)) {
        return null;
      }
      const value = parseFloat(control.value);
      return !isNaN(value) && value < this.minNumber ? {'minNumber': {'minNumber': this.minNumber, 'actual': control.value}} : null;  
  }
}
```

If I pass any value without binding to my custom directive, it works fine, however when I use biding, it throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'minNumber' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Here is where I use my custom directive:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="lun-size" name="lun-size" 
    [(ngModel)]="virtualDrive.si
    minNumber="{{ minSize }}"
    max="15"
    ngControl="size"
    required>
```

Anyone could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You should use `@Input` for that otherwise write `minNumber="12"` because `minNumber` in your case is property binding

Comment: Attribute binding only works for statically added values, not for bound values. `minNumber="12345"` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
@Input()
minNumber: number;
```

instead of using the constructor?

also... I've noticed that when you have a validator like this that takes an input you have to jump through quite a few hoops to have the validation re-run when minNumber changes. take a look at [MaxLengthValidator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3e685f98c666fcb9f0556ccb65d4b40716ac2985/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L253) to get an idea how you might proceed.

Comment: The @Input() is a basic resource I had forget from the tutorials, thanks.

The @Attribute on the constructor is a replacement for the @Input?